# Duvida mysql query + php

Tags: php, mysql

Gero uma data no PHP e salvo no banco de dados:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$timestamp = strtotime($today);
```

No banco ela fica salva nesse formato: `1474496101`

Quando faço um SELECT neste campo usando a query abaixo por exemplo, NAO VOLTA NADA.

```
SELECT * FROM teste.data WHERE data = FROM_UNIXTIME(1474496101)
```

alguém sabe me dizer por que ?

Comment: E como é definida a coluna `data` no banco de dados?

Comment: desculpa tive que editar pq faltou uma frase. o campo data é do tipo int

Comment: O nome da tabela é `teste.data` mesmo?

Comment: banco chama teste e a tabela data e o campo data

Comment: Certo. E se o tipo de `data` é `int`, por quê compara o valor da coluna com o retorno de `FROM_UNIXTIME`? Não deveria ser `data = 1474496101`?

Comment: Amigo você pode pegar a data atual diretamente pelo banco. Utilize a função now()

Comment: acho que você tem razão, para usar o FROM_UNIXTIME o tipo do campo deveria ser TIMESTAMP, correto?  foi inocência na hora de criar o banco.

Comment: estou querendo usar o grafana para fazer o gráfico e ele so aceita a query com FROM_UNIXTIME..

Comment: não funciona mudei o campo para TIMESTAMP ele foi para o formato 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

descobri!

no banco de dados não pode estar com formato de unixtime tem que estar com formato de timestamp por exemplo: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

fiz o teste agora e funcionou. 
de qualquer forma obrigado Anderson, seus comentários me levou a solução.